# Is ‘12ers’ well-established alias for 2012 Presidential candidate?

Tags: neologisms, popularity

I puzzled over the first line of the article of December 9’s *Time* magazine titled "Des Moines Dust-Up", which reads;

> '12ers (minus Huntsman) square-off at Drake University for ABC News/Yahoo! News/WOI-TV/Des Moines Register/Iowa GOP debate from 9 - 11 pm ET.

As it didn’t occur to me that *12ers* means 2012 Presidential candidates (until I reasoned it out by the context), I searched for definitions of *12ers* on Google, and found that only Wikipedia provides the following definition:

> ‘12"ers’ is a 1987/1988 remix album released by Phil Collins. The album contains six tracks from his 1985 hit album, No Jacket required, remixed.....

Is *12ers* widely-accepted as the word representing for 2012 presidential candidates? Do Americans immediately associate *12ers* with Presidential candidates, not Phil Collins’ album?

Is this word automatically renewed every 4 years as *04ers*, *08ers*, *16ers*, *20ers*, and *n＋4ers* without public consensus?

Comment: One would think finding no mention of it via Google would show that it is *not* "well-established".

Comment: The typical meaning of Twelvers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelver

Comment: Note the " in the Phil Collins album title, is notation for inch, so I'd pronounce it "12 inchers". From Wikipedia: *"The remixes on this album were originally released on various 12- inch LP singles"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*12ers* may not be simply *Time*-speak, as Prof. Lawler notes, but Washington-speak in general.

I searched for *08ers* on time.com, and turned up [this snippet](http://nationaljournal.com/search?query=08ers&controllerName=search&action=search):

> The AP continues its questions to the WH ’*08ers* with, “What time is
>   ‘sleeping in?’”

The article goes on to mention Hillary Clinton, John Edwards, Bill Richardson, Mitt Romney, Sam Brownback, Duncan Hunter, Barack Obama, Rudy Giuliani, John McCain, *et al.*, so apparently it was very early in the 2008 campaign.

Following *Time*'s reference to its source in the *National Journal*, I repeated the *08ers* search there, and found a [number of links referencing the 2008 campaign](http://nationaljournal.com/search?query=08ers&controllerName=search&action=search).

Repeating the search with *04ers*, however, turned up nothing, so either this construction originated with *08ers*, or the National Journal's searchable archives don't go back that far.

Addendum: Searching for *12ers* on NationalJournal.com turned up nothing. Perhaps they dropped the term after *Time* coopted it?

Comment: Considering how I’ve already got me some 54 [Fourteeners](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourteener) and 637 [Thirteeners](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirteener), I don’t think *Twelvers* are  even worth talking about.  But really, this is just trendy talk, and interferes with better-established uses of such terms.

Comment: @tchrist I agree -- 12ers is a clunky term no doubt formulated by those who want to pose as Washington cognoscenti. But I wonder if they realized that 08ers gets read as waiters? That's what many of the candidates would be if they didn't have the money to get into politics... (Wait, you've climbed or been on almost 700 peaks over 13,000 ft? Whoa.)

Answer (score 8):

No, it appears to be just *Time*-speak.

Perhaps it's formed by analogy with *Birthers*,

> 'Republicans who refuse to believe Barack Obama was born in the U.S.A.'

*12ers* might therefore mean

> 'Republicans who refuse to allow Barack Obama to run unopposed in 2012.'

Comment: I don't know about the analogy, but I agree I've never heard the term in any other elections.

Comment: I think even we in the UK would have noticed if there'd been 8-ers or 4-ers in recent presidential election alignments.

Comment: _Time-speak_ is well-established. See Wolcott Gibbs' famous [1936 parody of Henry Luce and his magazines](http://archives.newyorker.com/?i=1936-11-28#folio=022) in _The New Yorker_

Answer (score 4):

Cultural references have to start somewhere. Sounds like *Time* is trying to institute one.

Comment: I asked currency of “heartland shout-out” and “stemwinding one’s way through” in this forum yesterday, both of which appeared in an article of New York Times. Some users said they’ve never heard them, Some thought them odd. Time “scooped” 12ers. It seems as if American journals are racing for coinage of new words and novel ways of expression.